# Cannot launch without an active device

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am developing a flutter app via vs code, I closed vs code and opened it again and now when i run my code no device is showing to connect.
[image]

just like that,

it keeps searching and searching without finding any device.
and the end it shows a box telling "Cannot launch without an active device"
any idea??

please I need to solve this problem a soon as possible.

Comment: What device are you trying to test on?

Comment: I don't think it my device issue, because i have and emulator also that always appear in the device search, suddenly everything disappeared.